# how do I convert rows in a dataframe into multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list, text-analytics-api

I have large dataframe of the following type:

```
Part    Text
P1  a
P1  b
P2  c
P2  d
```

I want to transform this data into two formats

Expected output 1:

```
Part    Text
P1  ['a','b']
P2  ['c','d']
```

Expected output 2:

```
Part    Text
P1  ['ab']
P2  ['cd']
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: How about `df.groupby('Part').agg(list)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Part')['Text'].agg(list).reset_index()
df2 = df.groupby('Part')['Text'].agg(lambda x: [''.join(x.values)]).reset_index()

print(df1)
  Part    Text
0   P1  [a, b]
1   P2  [c, d]

print(df2)
  Part  Text
0   P1  [ab]
1   P2  [cd]
```